# Using a list object to store indices

Tags: loops

I have a dataset of FIFA 23 Player Analysis. I would like to remove some players whose contracts have expired by 2022. How do I store the indices of these players in a list?

Comment: That would depend on what language this is, which you have not identified.

Comment: Language: Python